# What is the need for WildCard when Object type is available?

Tags: java, generics, wildcard

What is the need for Wildcard when object can be used as parameter in function definition which can accept any objects when it is compared to unbounded type..

```
package wildCards;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class NeedForWildCard {
    public void processInput(List<String> values){

    //Insted of List<String> we could have used List<object> and what is the need for wildcard in here?

        for(String valueExtractor:values){
            System.out.println("values="+valueExtractor);
        }
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList<Integer> valuesInteger=new ArrayList<>();
        valuesInteger.add(100);
        valuesInteger.add(200);
        valuesInteger.add(300);
        NeedForWildCard example=new NeedForWildCard();
        example.processInput(valuesInteger);//valuesInteger is arguments since it is used in method call.
    }

}
```

Comment: You can use just Object but when you use List with a generic you are narrowing it down that it will accept only list but can be of any type. In object you could even pass an Integer or you could even pass a map. There is not limitation. Hence we need generics.

Comment: Are you sure you can use List<Object> there?

Comment: @Leo I think OP is saying instead of List<String> replacing it by Object. Only Object not List of Object.

Comment: @Leo i was just curious about the object type, which is the super-class of all objects ..hence the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's say you have a method as following (with a wildcard argument `Object` list)

```
public void getList(List<Object> list){
    ... 
}
```

And then in a different method you do the following

```
List<String> strList = new ArrayList<String>();
getList(strList);
```

The second line will through a compilation error

`The method getList(List<Object>) in the type TESTClass is not applicable for the arguments (List<String>)`

You can't reference an object with a completely different object.

Comment: What happen's to the theory of Object is a super-class of all Objects?

Comment: That is when you reference `ArrayList` with `List` with the same object type.. but this doesn't apply to `List<Object>` and `ArrayList<String>` as they are completely different objects (i.e. `List<Object>` as a whole is different object, not `Object` vs `String`). In this case you are doing something similar to `String str = new Integer();`

Comment: Now i get this,its like List<Object> is not a  super type of List<Integer> or List<Number> or any other Classes?

Comment: Thanks,just to confirm Object is a super Type of Integer, wherein List<Object> is not a super type of List<Integer>.